# Izpack installler failing on Windows with java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, izpack

Updated application to use bundled version of Java 14, was previously using Java 8

Worked okay on Windows dev machine , but on other machine failing on unpacking the data with:

```
com.izforge.izpack.api.exception.IzPackException: An error occured
in java.lang.Thread.run() at Thread.java:832
in com.izforge.izpack.installer.unpacker.UnpackerBase.run() at UnpackerBase.java:241
in com.izforge.izpack.installer.unpacker.UnpackerBase.unpack() at UnpackerBase.java:319
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
in com.izforge.izpack.installer.unpacker.UnpackerBase.unpack() at UnpackerBase.java:299
in com.izforge.izpack.installer.unpacker.UnpackerBase.unpack() at UnpackerBase.java:475
in com.izforge.izpack.installer.unpacker.UnpackerBase.unpack() at UnpackerBase.java:528
in com.izforge.izpack.installer.unpacker.UnpackerBase.unpack() at UnpackerBase.java:627
in com.izforge.izpack.installer.unpacker.UnpackerBase.extract() at UnpackerBase.java:673
in com.izforge.izpack.installer.unpacker.LooseFileUnpacker.unpack() at LooseFileUnpacker.java:92
in java.io.File. () at File.java:362
```

Can't see why, does it not work reliably with Java 14 ?

Comment: The last Line of the stacktrace says there is an Error in the File class. Also you say it only appears on some machines, are you sure this is not an permission issue. Or your Disk space is full?

Comment: No I have double checked that, no permissions or space issues.

Comment: After reading the source code I can tell this happens when the base directory doesn't match the expected full path of the file. If you can attach a debugger, put a breakpoint on [`FileUtil.getRelativeFileName()`](https://github.com/izpack/izpack/blob/master/izpack-tools/src/main/java/com/izforge/izpack/util/FileUtil.java#L233) and find out why it's returning `null`.

Answer (score 1):

There are some difference between jdk. Try to use jdk from:

1. https://adoptopenjdk.net/
2. https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk14-archive-downloads.html

Be sure that you change system path for new jdk, and you use another jdk that earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Does the other machine have java 14 jdk installed?
You can check the following folder on windows:

> C:\Program Files\Java

if you do have jdk-14 installed, try running inside the command prompt the following:

> "C:\Program Files\Java\YourJdkVersion\bin\java" -jar YourCompiledJar.jar

If the app runs correctly using the command above, it's because of the environment variable.
In that case, do the following:

> Right click My Computer and select Properties.
> On the Advanced tab, select Environment Variables, and then edit
> JAVA_HOME to point to where the JDK software is located, for example,
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_02. (should be something like jdk-14 in your case)

from docs.oracle.com

Comment: It uses Java 14 provided as part of the installation, but nevermind I have now switched to using JPackage